# function of two variables

Tags: functions

Sorry for the absolute rookie question.

I need to find an example of

f(x,y) =/= f(y,x), for all x, y.

Of course f(a,b) = ka+mb*i, k, m real would be an example, but is it possible that another function exists, whose range is entirely real? if no, then why not.

Thnaks for all help and hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=y$ and $f(x,x)$ is defined,  then $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$.

For $x\ne y$, we can use for example $f(x,y)=x-y$.  If we want to exclude the possibility $x=y$, we can use $\frac{1}{x-y}$.

Comment: Okey, And i have yet another question, similar to this. thus, to the moderators, shall I ask a new question, or shall I post it as a comment to this.

Comment: If you write it as a comment, there is a fair chance that no one will see it.

Comment: thank you for the heads up : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680550/another-question-of-function-of-two-variables